# How to iterate through an array with dynamic depth in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a list of specific directories I am getting absolute paths for, for my file inclusions. I have this function set up that iterates over my list because I know the file structure. I have been trying to devise a way to utilize the DirectoryIterator with and without the IteratorIterator but I can't get the control that I'm needing. Some of the directories, the image directories have subfolders as well, but those are dynamically called and I do not need them hard coded. This is the code I have but it is ugly.

```
 protected function getRoot() {
                $directories = [
            'css' => '',
            'demo' =>['clientImages',['config' => ['includes' => ['class','js']]],['src' => ['libs' => '']]],
            'includes' => ['class','inc','js'],
            'login' => ['logImages',['config' => ['includes' => ['class','js']]],['src' => ['libs' => '']]],
            'public' => [['config' => ['includes' => ['class','js']]],['src' => ['libs' => '']]],
            'recover' => [['config' => ['includes' => ['class','js']]],['src' => ['libs' => '']]],
            'registration' => [['config' => ['includes' => ['class','js']]],['src' => ['libs' => '']]],
            'siteImages' => '',
            'tracker' => ['clientImages',['config' => ['includes' => ['class','js']]],['src' => ['libs' => '']]]
        ];
        
        foreach($directories as $path => $dirs){
            $this->root[$path] = $this->getSiteRoot().$path.'/';
            
            if(is_array($dirs)){
                foreach($dirs as $dir => $sub){
                    if(is_array($sub)){
                        foreach($sub as $s => $d){
                                
                            $this->root[$path.'-'.$s] = $this->root[$path].$s.'/';
                            if(is_array($d)){
                                foreach($d as $b => $a){
                    
                                    $this->root[$path.'-'.$b] = $this->root[$path.'-'.$s].$b.'/';
                                    if(is_array($a)){
                                        foreach($a as $z){
                                            
                                            $this->root[$path.'-'.$z] = $this->root[$path.'-'.$b].$z.'/';
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                
                                $this->root[$path.'-'.$s] = $this->root[$path.'-'.$s].$d.'/';
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this->root[$path.'-'.$sub] = $this->root[$path].$sub.'/';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return $this->root;
}
```

To me, this is just ugly coding. Is there a more simple way to utilize the built in php functions to achieve the same thing? Or am I going to be stuck using this ugly code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your right way is recursive!

Add this function in your class.

```
protected function getPath($tree, $path = '', $root = ''){
    $pre = $root? "$root-": '';
    foreach($tree as $name => $subs){
        $dir = "$path$name/";
        $this->root["$pre$name"] = $this->getSiteRoot().$dir;
        if(is_array($subs)) $this->getPath($subs, $dir, $root);
    }
}
```

Now change your `getRoot` function to this. Assuming we have your `$directories`:

```
protected function getRoot() {
    $directories = [/* paste your directory tree */];
    $this->getPath($directories);
    return $this->root;
}
```

Comment: I don't use recursion very often, so I forget about it. But thank you. This is what I was trying to get :)